# error when trying to install Horde

Tags: php, linux, horde

When I'm trying to install Horde on a RHEL 6 box it says it cannot find /usr/bin/lib/Application.php.

Here is the output when I do the "webmail-install":

root:horde$ webmail-install

Warning: require_once(/usr/bin/lib/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/bin/webmail-install on line 17

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/bin/lib/Application.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /usr/local/bin/webmail-install on line 17

I have tried this about 5 times over the last two days starting with a fresh computer each time.  And I always get the same error.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you following a guide or something...did you try this? https://kyup.com/tutorials/install-horde/

Comment: Yes, I am following this: https://www.horde.org/apps/webmail/docs/INSTALL

Comment: That guide...I know that is the official guide, but, looks wrong...why they are compiling php from the source instead of just installing it....better follow the guide up

Comment: Yea, the guide at kyup does not cover RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when it ask for the application path, you have to put in /usr/bin/content.  Who knew?  Too bad they don't give out the information you need to install correctly.